# How to remove the margin that router-link adds to a button in VueJS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, router, routerlink

I've recently started using router-link for my elements. But for some reason the router-link adds some margin to the button that gives an awful look to the navbar(Bootstrap V4.6).

[router-link with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am0Dv.png)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/teams">Teams</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/admin">Admin</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/admin">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-light">Sign in</button>
      </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[router-link without button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEIgQ.png)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
  <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/">Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/teams">Teams</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/admin">Admin</router-link>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item my-xs-1 active mx-lg-2">
      <router-link class="nav-link" to="/admin"> Sign in </router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That looks like app specific CSS for `button`, `a`, or both; and not a direct cause of `router-link` or `button`. Use DevTools to inspect the button to determine the source of the margin.

Comment: You don't need to nest a button in router-link btw.  You could just give the router-link the button classes.